# Grails GWT project , how to share dto classes from server to client

Tags: grails, gwt

I have created a grails+Gwt project with gwt plugin from grails.

I am able to run a hello world .

Next, I am trying to return some dto class from server to client.

But it always gets failed.

```
    No source code is available for type domainclasses.UserEntity; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I have placed this entity/dto class in the domain package .

Also added in my Application.gwt.xml

```
         <source path='domain.domainclasses'/>
```

I am unable to understand how to deal with/ where to place entity/dto classes in case of Grails/GWT Project

screenshot of my project structure:
                  http://screencast.com/t/JVRrTxto70

please guide.

thanks

Comment: The source path attribute should be a file path that is relative to your GWT module XML file, not a package name.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, I think you might have to create a second GWT module for your domain classes and import it using <inherits ...> in your primary GWT module.

Comment: Where is the client package located? the domain package should be in the same level. As @TrogDor mentionned, it should be relative to GWT xml module descriptor and not the whole project

Comment: client package is under GWT package, if i add the domain package under GWT , then it will not accessible to service/asyncservice , which are under Java package:And also the RdbHelper class which is actually sending the entity back to client  ,  screenshot:  http://screencast.com/t/TI5ebhreVzCC